# Redirect Local DNS redirect a specific IP address

Tags: networking, dns, redirect, ip-forward

Apologies if this question already exists. I tried some topic answers, but isn't working yet!

I need to redirect some URLs to a specific IP, how can I do it in my PC? I need to redirect all traffic from "contactlist.local" to "192.168.86.15" and "pudim.com.br" to "192.168.86.16". But just if using my machine, I can't configure routers, switches and cable modem.

How can I do it?

Im using Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

I tried to create the file `/etc/named.conf` but nothing happens too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve `contactlist.local` to 192.168.86.15 add following line at the end of `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.86.15    contactlist.local
192.168.86.16    pudim.com.br
```

This change only effects your Ubuntu box not your router, modem, etc. How to do it depend on your network topology and devices and is out of range of this community.